# Create views with a column dropped for all tables in the database

Tags: sql-server, view

My database has a large amount of tables, lets call them Table1, Table2, Table3 and so on, which I need to setup for merge replication meaning that SQL Server will create a new Column (rowguid) in each table.

This is problematic for my front end (which I can't change) so my idea right now is to create a View of each table with the rowguid-column removed and place them under an own schema.

Due to the large number of tables and the large number of columns in each table this is not easily done manually so now I'm trying to write some SQL-code for this.
Without success I must say.

What I need is a recursive code that creates a new view of each table (named to the same name as the table but under a new schema) but omits the rowguid column in every table.

I have found out how I can drop the rowguid column without having to explicitly know the column names (they vary from table to table).

```
SELECT * INTO #TemporaryTable FROM [dbo].[Table1]
ALTER TABLE #TemporaryTable DROP COLUMN rowguid
SELECT * FROM #TemporaryTable

DROP TABLE #TemporaryTable
```

But how to combine this with CREATE VIEW (can only have one SELECT as I understand) and then also get it to go through all tables in my database is far beyond my competence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to do this would be to use Dynamic SQL. `CREATE VIEW` must, however, be the only statement in the batch, meaning that if you want to create one for every table, then you either need to use dynamic dynamic SQL (yes, I said that), or use a `CURSOR`. The prior would be more performant for a large amount of tables but the latter is easier to read (and write). If this is a one off process then I'm less concerned about the performance though, so I'll go down the `CURSOR` route.

```
CREATE SCHEMA vw; --Create a schema for the views
GO

DECLARE Tables CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
       t.[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sys.columns c
              WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                AND c.[name] = N'rowguid'); --Incase you have tables without this, as I assume you don't need views of those

DECLARE @SchemaName sysname,
        @TableName sysname,
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

OPEN Tables;

FETCH NEXT FROM Tables
INTO @SchemaName, @TableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    PRINT N'Creating View for object ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'.';

    --Create the dynamic statement
    SET @SQL = N'CREATE VIEW vw.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' AS' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
               N'    SELECT ' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                                              N'           ' + QUOTENAME(C.[name])
                                       FROM sys.columns c
                                            JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                                            JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                                       WHERE t.[name] = @TableName
                                         AND s.name = @SchemaName
                                         AND c.[name] != N'rowguid'
                                       ORDER BY c.column_id ASC
                                       FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,14,N'') + @CRLF +
              N'    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N';'

    PRINT @SQL; --Incase you need to the code run for debugging

    --Create the View
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    --Get next object
    FETCH NEXT FROM Tables
    INTO @SchemaName, @TableName;

END;

CLOSE Tables;
DEALLOCATE Tables;
```

*Note, this will fail if you have 2 tables on different schemas with the same name.*

Comment: Only thing is that it also includes all System Tables and I don't understand how to omit that. :)

Comment: That's easy enough, @Quist , just add `AND t.[type] = 'U'` in the `WHERE` for the `CURSOR` declaration.